# Apps route redirecting the wrong URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-controller, laravel-route, laravel-formrequest

------Platform Laravel 7x. --------

I am stuck in a simple problem. I can't find the error. While I am updating a form, it redirects to a wrong URL which I don't want and data doesn't update.

Form action url:

```
 method="POST" action="{{'city/update/'. $editCity->id}}"
```

[form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U30Eq.png)

Route:

```
Route::post('city/update/{id}','Admin\CityController@update');
```

[web route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of3cI.png)

Function from controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $editCity=City::find($id);
        $editCity->city_name=$request->city_name;
        $editCity->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

[function from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlmW5.png)

When I click on update it goes to this URL and shows 404 error which I don't want:
`public/panel/city/edit/city/update/33`

Help me to find out the problem where is the mistake I have done. I want to make it updated when I click on the update button and return back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use name route instead.
So your code will look like :

**blade.php**

```
method="POST" action="{{ route('city.update',  $editCity->id) }}"
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('city/update/{id}','Admin\CityController@update')->name('city.update');
```

Comment: Now it shows error for edit page, Error: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Missing required parameters for [Route: city.update] [URI: panel/city/update/{id}]. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\tolethunt\resources\views\admin\editCity.blade.php)

Comment: thanks, buddy. It works. Can you please tell me where I have done mistake without the name route? I want to learn.

Comment: Your mistake seems like that : `method="POST" action="{{ url('city/update/'. $editCity->id) }}"` hope this also works

Comment: You can also try this : `method="POST" action="/city/update/{{ $editCity->id }}"` hope you understand. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

In case your CityController is a resource controller, this what you should try:

```
Route: web.php

Route::resource('city', 'Admin\CityController');
```

```
Form: HTML

<form action="{{route('city.update',$editCity->id)}}" method="post">
```

```
Controller: CityController.php

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $editCity=City::find($id);
        $editCity->city_name=$request->city_name;
        $editCity->save();
        return back()->with('success','city added successfully!');
    }
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.   this error occurred. I didn't use a resource controller. But after implementing your code I got that error.

Comment: While creating your controller did you run such command ?: 

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\CityController --resource

```

You should create the controller as a resource controller, then declare it 

in your routes like this: 

```
Route::resource('city', 'Admin\CityController');  
```

Ps: Make sure to remove in web.php, your old route:  
```
Route::post('city/update/{id}','Admin\CityController@update')->name('city.update');
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating your controller did you run such command ?:

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\CityController --resource
```

You should create the controller as a resource controller, then declare it

in your routes like this:

```
Route::resource('city', 'Admin\CityController');
```

Ps: Make sure to remove in web.php, your old route:

```
Route::post('city/update/{id}','Admin\CityController@update')->name('city.update');
```

Comment: The problem is solved in another way. But I want to learn your way. I didn't create a resource controller. It only make:Admin\cityController
So, if I create a resource controller, is the route will be same for edit, update, delete? and what should I have to pass in the delete and edit button href?

Comment: Yeah. In case you want to perform intensive CRUD operations, it always good to declare your controller as a resource controller. Laravel will automatically create the HTTP verbs for you.